# Numbering cells in a grid using opencv python

Tags: python, django, opencv

I have created grids on an image with open cv, and I am trying to number the cells created from 1,2,3,4,5,... [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4mDu.jpg) shows what the result of this code is. Does anyone have an idea of how to get all the cells numbered in python ?

```
x = 0
y = 0
k = 0
while x < self.img.shape[1]:
    cv2.line(self.img, (x, 0), (x, self.img.shape[0]), color=(220,220,220), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, thickness=1)

    while y < self.img.shape[0]:
          cv2.line(self.img, (0, y), (self.img.shape[1], y), color=(220,220,220), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, thickness=1)
           y += 100
           k += 1
           cv2.putText(self.img, str(k),
                    (x,y), font,
                    1, (0, 255, 255),
                    1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
    x += 100
```

Comment: Your last line (x += 100) does not look to be properly indented. Or is it a copy/paste error ? If yes please edit the question.

Comment: sorry was a copy/paste error, just corrected that...

Comment: you have to reset y (to 0) if you start a new column

Comment: @berak I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work, or where would you suggest I do the reset.  Cause reseting y means the grid might not be completed